# Problem Loading Plug-Ins in QGIS 2.2 on Mac

Tags: qgis, python, osx

I'm trying to load the 'processing' module in QGIS (2.2.0-Valmiera on Mac  OSX 10.8).  However, this module and others (e.g. GarminaCustomMap) re failing to load with a message:

**ImportError: No module named osgeo**

I recently upgraded to Python 3 and have a suspicion this may be causing the problem.  Is this likely to be the case and is there a workaround other than downgrading back to Python 2.7 ?

I'm using the pre-compiled version of QGIS and I've seen another post on this forum that indicates QGIS includes it's own version of Python, so perhaps the problem lies elsewhere?

Thanks